# Avoid calling private method from module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, methods, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there any possibility to make private method in module ?
I want to prevent to call method from other modules.

```rb
module A
    private
    
    def name # this method can be used in module B
        "name"
    end
end

module B
    def print_name
        puts name
    end
end

module C
    include A
    include B
end

class Z
    include C
end

Z.new.print_name # want to throw NoMethodError
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write the following.

```
module A
  def name
    "name from A"
  end
end

module B
  def print_name
    "name from B"
  end
end

module C
  include A
  include B
  def self.included(klass)
    B.instance_methods(false).each { |m| klass.send(:private, m) }
  end
end

class Z
  include C
  def test
    print_name
  end
end
```

Then

```
Z.instance_methods.include?(:name)
  #=> true
Z.private_instance_methods.include?(:print_name)
  #=> true
```

```
z = Z.new
  #=> #<Z:0x00007fb0f810ad28>
```

```
z.name
  #=> "name from A"
z.print_name
  #=> NoMethodError: private method 'print_name' called for #<Z:0x00007fb0f810ad28>
z.test
  #=> "name from B"
```

See [Module#included](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-included). This is one of several so-called ["hook methods"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ruby-hook-methods/#:%7E:text=Ruby%20Hook%20Methods%20are%20called,picture%20when%20certain%20events%20occur.).

---

Suppose `Z` were as follows.

```
class Z
  def print_name
    "name from Z"
  end
  include C
  def test
    print_name
  end
end
```

Then

```
z.print_name
  #=> NoMethodError: private method 'print_name' called for #<Z:0x00007fb0f810ad28>
z.test
  #=> "name from Z"
```

This demonstrates that it is the original public method `Z#print_name` has been made private. Note:

```
C.ancestors
  #=> [Z, C, B, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```